# boto3 installed yet getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, boto3, aws-cloud9

In an AWS Cloud9 IDE, when running

```
sudo pip install boto3 && sudo pip3 install --upgrade awscli && python3 permissions.py
```

the first two parts work fine and then in the last part I get

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "permissions.py", line 4, in
>
> import boto3
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3'

[image: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'boto3']

The permissions.py file has at the top

```
import boto3
```

If I run `pip freeze` can see that boto3 is installed

```
astroid==2.3.0
awscli==1.18.165
backcall==0.2.0
boto3==1.16.5
botocore==1.19.5
colorama==0.4.3
decorator==4.4.2
Django==2.0.2
docutils==0.15.2
git-remote-codecommit==1.15.1
ikp3db==1.4.1
importlib-metadata==2.0.0
ipython==7.16.1
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
isort==4.3.21
jedi==0.11.1
jmespath==0.10.0
lazy-object-proxy==1.5.1
mccabe==0.6.1
parso==0.1.1
pbr==5.5.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
prompt-toolkit==3.0.8
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
Pygments==2.7.2
pylint==2.4.4
pylint-django==2.3.0
pylint-flask==0.6
pylint-plugin-utils==0.6
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
PyYAML==5.3.1
rsa==4.5
s3transfer==0.3.3
six==1.15.0
stevedore==3.2.2
traitlets==4.3.3
typed-ast==1.2.0
urllib3==1.25.11
virtualenv==16.2.0
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
virtualenvwrapper==4.8.4
wcwidth==0.2.5
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.4.0
```

Comment: It sounds like the module is installed inside a different Python installation than the one you were using for the script, though at this point that is simply conjecture. In the future, verify where pip and pip3 install their packages to. This could likely have been prevented by using the same interpreter to run pip with, so `python3 -m pip install boto3 && python3 script.py`.

Comment: if you switched the user, example sudo to root then you would encounter that error, the fix is as mentioned by Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to solve it, I just changed the command to

```
python permissions.py
```

[image: DONE as expected]